# MongoDB C# 2.0 upserting sub item in collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

This is the code I have so far.

```
var filter = Builders<UserEntity>.Filter.Where(s => s.user_bd_id == userid && s.entities_engaged.Any(i => i.item_bd_id == itemid));
var update = Builders<UserEntity>.Update.Set(s => s.entities_engaged[-1].engagement_weight, weight);
var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

And this is the collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59efdf83cb5e19e2b840e6ed"),
    "user_bd_id" : 0,
    "entities_engaged" : [ 
        {
            "item_bd_id" : 10,
            "engagement_weight" : 500.0
        }
    ]
}
```

All works well if the document exists, if entities_engaged sub list exists, and if the sub item in the list exists. How can I convert this code into an upsert? I tried using

```
await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

but it does not work.

Also, I wanted to know how can I increase `engagement_weight`. The code above overrides the value, but I would like to use something like `engagement_weight = engagement_weight + 1`

Comment: So what is not working ? So upsert doesn't create a document ?

Comment: Yes. I can not make it work.

Comment: Also look [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3326) for more info